# Jquery image upload not working in firefox

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-ui

The image uploading is not working in firefox at the first time but its working fine in google chrome how to solve this and also i need to restrict the image format how can i restrict that in this code please help me friends. . .

```
     $('#imgInp').focusout(function () {

            function readURL(input) {
                if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
                    }

                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                }
            }
            $("#imgInp").change(function () {
                if ($('#imgInp').val() != "No file chosen") {
                    readURL(this);
                }
                else {
                    alert("Insert Photo");
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Have you debug it on firefox? If yes did you have any exception?

Comment: No the first time image was not uploaded after that second time its uploaded in firefox

Comment: So while debugging you don't get any errors. Just the image not upload with the first. Am i understand right?

Comment: Yes your are right. . .